# Is $|K+\partial_jK|\leq C e^{-2\epsilon |x|^2}$? $(K(x,t)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2} e^{-|x|^2/4t})$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $K(x,t)= (4\pi t)^{-n/2} e^{-|x|^2/4t} \ (t>0, x\in \mathbb R^n)$.
Note that $$\partial_jK(x,t)= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}K(x,t)= (4\pi t)^{-n/2} e^{-|x|^2/4t}x_j (2t)^{-1}$$

> Question: Can we say that there exist $C>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that 
>   $$|K(x,t)|+ |\partial_jK(x,t)| \leq C e^{-2\epsilon |x|^2}$$ on $x\in \mathbb R^n, 0<a<t<b$ (for fixed $a,b \in \mathbb R).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have certainly a $C_0$ such that $|K(x,t)| \leq C_0 e^{-|x|^2/4t}$ by setting $C_0 = \textbf{sup}_{t \in (a,b)} (4\pi t)^{-n/2}$. In the same vein we have $|K_j(x,t)| \leq (4\pi t)^{-n/2} \cdot |x_j| \cdot  e^{-|x|^2/4t} \leq C_1 e^{-|x|^2/4t}$ where $C_1 = C_0 \cdot |x_j|$. Now just let $C_2 = \textbf{max}\{C_0,C_1\}$ then it follows that $|K(x,t)| + |K_j(x,t)| \leq 2C_2 e^{-|x|^2/4t}$. Now once again we can redefine   $2C_2=C$ and so $|K(x,t)| + |K_j(x,t)| \leq C e^{-|x|^2/4t}$. Take a look at the following expression in the product,

$$\frac{1}{e^{\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}}$$

and notice that it gets larger if $t_n$ is an decreasing sequence of numbers and vice-versa otherwise i.e  we would have to be able to choose an $\epsilon$ such that for all $t \in (a,b)$ we have,

$$ 2\epsilon < \frac{1}{4t}$$

$\textbf{Question}$: How can you pick such an $\epsilon$?

$\textbf{Update}$: Yes, I have assumed that $x$ lies in a compact subset, otherwise we cannot bound the $j$-partial.

Comment: @FA: Thanks: since $a<t<b,$ we have $(4b)^{-1}\leq (4t)^{-1}.$ So  we  may take $\epsilon= (8b)^{-1}.$

Comment: @FA: Thanks, But it seems that $C$ depends on $x$? Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct. I have assumed that $x$ lies in some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Otherwise we cannot bound $K_j(x,t)$. So without this, we would say no, this is not possible.